# Using Parentheses within R1C1 Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-r1c1-notation

I am having issues with the R1C1 function. I am trying to search a column (A) in a worksheet and, if a value is found, paste a formula into the cell 8 rows to the right. The formula is using the R1C1 function, as it references different cells each time. The problem I am having is that the R1C1 formula does not seem to accept parentheses within the formula, which will be needed in order for the math to work out correctly for many of the other formulas I will need to use. Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Dim filledcell As Object
    For Each filledcell In TemplateTab.Range("A2:A" & TemplateTab.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If filledcell = "Cell" Then
        filledcell.Offset(, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[0]C[-7]/R[0]C[-5])/R[0]C[-1]"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It work for me, what are you getting

Comment: you may want to declare `filledcell` as range: `Dim filledcell As Range`

Answer (score 0):

the formula works fine for me, what makes you think it is not accepting the parentheses?